# Google Analytics seems set up properly but still shows 'Tracking Not Installed'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics, haml

I am trying to set up Google Analytics for my Ruby on Rails project. Here is the script I've put in my base template:

```
:javascript
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'MY_ID', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

This is how it is rendered (from page source):

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'MY_ID', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

I been using Google's Analytics Debugger extension for chrome to see what's going on but I'm not entirely sure what I should be looking for to confirm it is in fact working. Here is what is displayed:

```
Initializing Google Analytics. analytics_debug.js:10
Running command: ga(create, MY_ID, auto) analytics_debug.js:10
Creating new tracker: t0 analytics_debug.js:10
Auto cookieDomain found: "none" analytics_debug.js:10
Running command: ga(send, pageview) analytics_debug.js:10

Sent beacon:
[EXCLUDED]

analytics_debug.js:10
adSenseId        (&a)   1151974650 analytics_debug.js:10
apiVersion       (&v)   1 analytics_debug.js:10
clientId         (&cid) MY_CLIENT_ID analytics_debug.js:10
encoding         (&de)  UTF-8 analytics_debug.js:10
flashVersion     (&fl)  14.0 r0 analytics_debug.js:10
hitType          (&t)   pageview analytics_debug.js:10
javaEnabled      (&je)  1 analytics_debug.js:10
language         (&ul)  en-us analytics_debug.js:10
location         (&dl)  http://MY_URL analytics_debug.js:10
screenColors     (&sd)  24-bit analytics_debug.js:10
screenResolution (&sr)  1920x1200 analytics_debug.js:10
title            (&dt)  MY_PROJECT analytics_debug.js:10
trackingId       (&tid) MY_ID analytics_debug.js:10
viewportSize     (&vp)  1722x734
```

I'm pretty stumped here so all help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm going to assume that `MY_ID` is the correct Google Analytics ID in 'UA-XXXX-Y' format?

Comment: Yes I redacted any information I thought to be sensitive

Comment: What happens when you load the page and look at real-time reports? Anything there?

Comment: Where would I find that? In the analytics dashboard?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am experiencing the same

Answer (score 0):

Everything you have looks correct to me. If this is a brand new account, sometimes it can take up to 24 hours to see your data.

I wouldn't spend too much more time trying to debug this. If you still don't see anything tomorrow, comment on this answer and let me know.

Comment: You can also verify in Real-Time reports whether you tracking code is tracking live hits. And if so, then as Philip said, everything should be fine and it is just a matter of time before data shows up in your reports.